# Error fatal al realizar git push a repositorio existente

Tags: git, github, git-push

Estoy tratando de realizar un git push desde un equipo distinto a donde inicialmente cree el repositorio en GitHub. Lo eh intentado de dos maneras, la primera desde el editor VS CODE y la segunda, desde el git bash.

Ya configure el usuario y el email . pero me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: git]

No tuve problemas al agregar los archivos provisionalmente y tampoco tuve inconvenientes al realizar el commit.

Adicional a esto, les comento que ya agregue otra llave privada de SSH para trabajar en este equipo de computo que es el de mi trabajo

Comment: ¿Cambiaste el usuario con el que haces push? ¿Cambiaste algo en la configuración de git en tu terminal? Todo indica que estás intentando hacerlo con un usuario diferente, en github el unico contributor es GspindolaB pero dice que intentas hacer push con guillermospindola

Comment: puedes hacer un git remote -v para ver si estas en el repositorio correcto

Comment: Hola, pude resolverlo agregando un nuevo contributor al repositorio. Muchas gracias por responder, saludos.